# How to get a custom query running in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a Page to display a custom query using the snippet posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/alternative-to-query-posts-for-main-loop). The following is in my `functions.php`:

```
function alter_the_query($request) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();
    $dummy_query->parse_query($request);
    // this is the actual manipulation
    if($dummy_query->is_page('blog')) $request['category_name'] = 'Blog';
    // and then
    return $request;
}
add_filter('request','alter_the_query');
```

The page called "Blog" has a basic loop inside- so it should be displaying whatever `WP_Query` tells it to. However, it is only displaying the Page content- which should have been ignored.

I can't seem to find a reference that explains the properties of the `$request` object, so I'm not sure what I should do to make this snippet work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this happens because you didn't change $request['pagename'] value, so wp try to load content for this pages.

Update this should work for you

```
function alter_the_query($request) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();
    $dummy_query->parse_query($request);
    // this is the actual manipulation
    if($dummy_query->is_page('blog')) {
      $request['category_name'] = 'Blog';
      unset($request['pagename']);
    }
    // and then
    return $request;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for the properties of `$request`?

Comment: Request have same properties as attribute public_query_vars in WP class (wp-includes/class-wp.php line 18). Also look at private_query_vars attribute. Description for parameters here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Comment: About error: This looks like you didn't return value from your filter or returned value is not array.

Comment: Yes, it does. But I don't know _why_. I fiddled a little more with a slightly different method (altering `$query_vars`) but only accomplished a display of every single page on a single layout. It can't be so difficult to do what I'm trying to do. The support forum has dozens of people asking for the same thing and no answers. I'm obviously missing something about how to manipulate the query.

Comment: I try this code on my test wordpress installation and this works. May be i misunderstood your problem. Why you don't not create different template for your page and use query_posts from this template?

Comment: @hadvig let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1918/discussion-between-isaac-lubow-and-hadvig)